# How to validate react input fields with some custom validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I am working with react and making some new input fields dynamically, and using [React-gook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) for validation.

What I am doing is -

1. I have one dropdown in which I have numbers as dropdown, like 1,2,3,4
2. So which ever dropdown user is selecting I am creating that much input field
3. if user selects 3 then 3 input fields

What I am trying to achieve is

1. When user create two input fields i do not want both of them to have same input.
2. Like if first input is having D as input then the second one should not take `D` in second one.

PS- here just for minimal code i am creating only one set of input, like first name

It can be when i select 2 then I can create two set of inputs having Fname and Lname in each set so there both fname should not take same value and same goes for lname.

What I have done

this one to hold the state, initial one is selected and one input is created.

```
const [initialSet, setinitialSet] = useState(1);
```

On select change doing this

```
    const Select_change = (e) => {
    let val = parseInt(e.target.value);
    setinitialSet(val);
  };
```

Now using that initial state to loop my elements to create input fields

```
<div className="row">
      {[...Array(initialSet).keys()].map((li, index) => (
        <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              type="text"
              name={`data[${index}].name`}
              id={"name" + index}
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="F Name"
              ref={register({ required: `F name ${index} is required` })}
            />
            <label" htmlFor={"name" + index}>
              F Name
            </label>
            {errors.data && errors.data[index] && errors.data[index].name && (
              <div>
                <span className="text-danger">
                  {errors.data[index].name.message}
                </span>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
```

Now I just want to validate the fname so that two input fields of f name should not have same input.

[Code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-water-194pr?file=/src/App.js)

I have full working code in my code sandbox

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array of inputs so when you select 3 you create an array with 3 elements that will contain the data.

`const [initialSet, setinitialSet] = useState([]);`

and here's the creation process:

```
const Select_change = (e) => {
  let val = parseInt(e.target.value);
  setinitialSet( new Array(val));
}
```

optionally you can initialise the array to zeros if you want

`setinitialSet( new Array(val).fill(0) );`

When you loop over the inputs you will use the index of the element in the array.
You can even store names and errors in each element of the element if you want a complicated logic.

Comment: No no, there must be some simple solution using `react-hook-form`, which I am missing here, the way u are saying will complicate the things